# log4net 1.2.12 Console Application (null)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, null, log4net, log4net-configuration

I am experiencing a strange issue with newest version of log4net 1.2.12
**My Log file is created successfully without issue**, anyway also a (null) file is always created in the same directory of the Exe file.

This is my xml config file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelMatchFilter">
        <levelToMatch value="DEBUG"/>
        <acceptOnMatch value="false"/>
      </filter>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5.5level] %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <threshold value="ALL"/>
      <File type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}"/>
      <param name="appendToFile" value="false"/>
      <param name="maximumFileSize" value="20000KB"/>
      <param name="maxSizeRollBackups" value="200"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%-5.5level] %logger - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

and this is how I call it from my main:

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The logger
    /// </summary>
    private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

    /// <summary>
    /// The CMD line args
    /// </summary>
    public static Arguments CmdLineArgs = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Main.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">The arguments.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CmdLineArgs = new Arguments();

            Parser CmdLineParser = new Parser();

            if (CmdLineParser.ParseArguments(args, CmdLineArgs))
            {
                log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = CmdLineArgs.LogFile;
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

                CmdLineArgs.PrintArguments(args);
                CmdLineArgs.Check();
                CmdLineArgs.PrintArguments();
            }
            else
            {
                CmdLineArgs.PrintArguments(args);
                Console.WriteLine(CmdLineArgs.GetUsage());
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Return Code: {0}", 2));

                return 2;
            }

            logger.Info("Execution Terminated");
            logger.Info(string.Format("Return Code: {0}", 0));

            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (logger.IsInfoEnabled)
            {
                logger.Fatal("Fatal Error:", ex);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Return Code: {0}", 8));
            }

            logger.Info(string.Format("Return Code: {0}", 8));

            return 8;
        }
    }
}
```

This perfectly works with log4net 1.2.11 and previous, but with log4net 1.2.12 a (null) file is created.

I am using VS2012 and .net 4.0 Framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a line like

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

in your AssemblyInfo.cs.

That will initialise log4net and create your (null) logfile when the first log4net dll access takes place, which in your example is when it executes the line

```
private static ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
```

This will happen before the Main method is called and before your Logfile property is set.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is because you get an instance of `ILog` in a static field: that static field will be created before the configuration code has run and the log file name has been set, hence creating a null file as `LogFileName` is null.

Then, when you set the log file name and call `Configure()` the second file is created.

Answer (score 0):

Try change

```
<File type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}"/>
```

to become

```
<param name="file" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}"/>
```

Comment: I have tried with your suggestion but I have experienced the same issue.